# looking for a code to access Rest Service thru SSO using java

Tags: spring, rest, single-sign-on

I have a client/consumer application that needs to access the Rest Services from the provider application. However, i need to go thru SSO first before accessing the Rest Services. Manually pasting the SSO URL with the parameters, I was successfully redirected to the provider app. However, I need to do it from java class and get the token after SSO so i can use the token to call the Rest Services. can anyone point me to the right direction, please?

Comment: Have a look at spring security, you might need to implement your own authenticationprovider:

Comment: thanks Marged. But i think Spring Security is from a provider app perspective. is that right? Can i use Spring Security as a client/consumer app of the SSO?

Comment: You can cause SS to redirect to your Sso, grab or validate auth info and then have SS in turn assert the received information

Comment: hi Marged. Can you point me to the section where that is being done? I am reading the Spring Security docs but most of them are about service provider and IDP. I would really appreciate a lot if you can show me some examples or documentation.

Comment: Hi Marged. I read thru the SS SAML docs many times and I still could not figure out how to make this work. I have downloaded and deployed the sample codes but it is from the Service Provider point of view. If you can just give me an idea where to start, I will be very grateful.

Comment: this has been answered in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164958/can-net-application-pass-the-sso-token-to-java-application-for-calling-rally-re/31231916#31231916