# can .net application pass the SSO token to java application for calling Rally Rest services?

Tags: java, .net, rally

I have a java application that is creating reports based on QC data. I want the same application to create reports based on Rally data. However, Rally as of this time has no SSO api for java but .net. So, I was thinking if it is possible for .net to handover the token to java application after SSO authentication so that Java application can use the token when calling the Rest Services. Does anyone have any comment if it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems overly cumbersome. I would recommend using Rally's API Key for authentication using the Java REST toolkit. Note that you can authenticate to Rally using API Key, even if your Subscription is set to SSO-Only authentication. This Rally Knowledgebase FAQ has details:

https://na20.salesforce.com/articles/Article/Oauth-Client-and-ApiKey-FAQ